# retrieving data - SQLite query vs storing and retrieving data from memory

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, arraylist

I have the following data structure for a movies SQLite db (i will keep it simple , the real tables have more fields):

- genre - (id , name)
- movie - (id , genreId , name , year)
- scenes - (id , movieId , name)

for example:

- genre - (7 , thriller)
- movie - (250 , 7 , The Sixth Sense , 1999)
- scenes - (15 , 250 , I see dead people)

I have the data stored in an SQLite db on my Android app.
I have a data manager class that I use to retrive relevant data.

I need to be able to do the following:

- get ALL genres
- get ALL movies per genre id (+ the abbilty to sort according to different fields)
- get a SPECIFIC movie item according to movie id
- get ALL scenes according to movie id
- ...

I would like to know, performance-wize, what is the better way to approach this data:

1. perform a SQLite query every time I need to get data.
2. after getting data once from th db, store it in an array list and thus keeping it in memory, for example - ArrayList of genres, where a Genre object holds an array list of Movie objects...
3. same as option 2 but with hash maps. in that case - when looping over the map, is there a way to control the order of the objects?
4. any other option that comes to mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you retrieve data from database and use CursorAdapter to represent data in a ListView. So, I guess this is the most effective way. If you have different activities for your tables, until activities are destroyed they will store your data in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment:) ListView is not always the case in my project. I want to have a more generic way to fetch that data so it will fit all of the scenarios possible

Comment: In any case it's better to work with Cursors than with ArrayLists because Cursors will be faster.

Comment: but what about the the db query you use to get the curser? isn't it better to keep the results in memory than to perform a query every time you need data?

Comment: it is better to use query every time rather than keeping result in memory